# Ionic 3 - ion-slides disappear on keyboard open

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am adding dynamic forms in slider, so that multiple forms can be visible with swap. But when keyboard opens ion-slides is disappears. please suggest a solution.

[image]

[image]

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 browser 5.0.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v9.4.0
npm               : 5.6.0 
OS                : macOS High Sierra
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use following CSS it will work.

```
.scroll-content{
margin-bottom: 0px !important;
padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But content below textarea is covered by keyboard and cant scroll. Even it is not the  solution I wanted, but something is better than nothing. Cheers.

Comment: For me, only using the latter rule (`padding-bottom`) worked, and no content gets hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly!! output came normal with ion-slides tag surrounded by div tag. If you have any explanation, please share.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with ion-slide and can confirm that wrapping it in  tags solves the issue as per yohoprashant's answer.

The issue only happens in Android but not iOS